# Strange Behavior of Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-3.5

I dont get the error when my development database is active

The production database gives the error, the only difference is DATA !!!
How possibly can this happen ?

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

Comment: Are you using cascading dropdown lists or some other dynamic controls on the page?

Comment: Sure ! but I cant figure out why data makes difference ?!

Comment: Two suggests.  1. You should put @user for the person you're responding, that way they are notified you're answering them.  2. Are you using Ajax Control Toolkit cascading dropdown by any chance?  Because if you are you're probably running into [this](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=10109) issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did run into a similar issue with the Cascading Dropdowns.
Here are various ways into solving this issue:

1. Create a derived class for the dropdownlist as done [here](http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/cascadingdropdown-causes-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-error/)
2. The detailed info can be found [here](http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/revised-cascadingdropdown-causes-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-error/)

I hope that it will help